# Populating jqGrid with data from model view already sent to the client

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid, viewmodel

I'm new to web development.  I am currently working on a ASP.NET MVC 2 project that needs to use a jqGrid to display the results of a search.

Now every single jqGrid tutorial that I found has the grid filled by calling its own specific action in the controller.  However, I have various search categories on my page, each with their own form that calls the appropriate action when submitted.  Each action then returns a list of results.

Is there a way to populate the jqGrid using the view model that has been returned by one of the search actions?  If so, could you specify a small example?  If not, how can I populate the jqGrid when submitting search criteria by clicking the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Found another way.  Upon submitting the action corresponding to the search category still gets used, but instead of returning the results it stores the results in the session cache:

HttpContext.Session["Response"] = _repository.search(criteria);

Then when the page refreshes, the jqGrid action gets used to retrieve the cached results and populates the grid.